# What is the backing store used for persistent messages in RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

Where does RabbitMq store persistent messages, i.e. which backing store is used for persisting messages by RabbitMq

Answer (score 0):

The messages are stored in Ram by default, you can choose the lazy mode to save them on the hard disk if you want.

Generally, messages are kept in ram, postponed messages are moved to the hard disk to be retried.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ uses [Mnesia](https://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html) to store the configurations as Users/Vhosts/Queues definitions etc.. and it uses a custom database to store the queues data.
the database is (usually) located in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@<<hostname>>/` see also: https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html

There are different types of queues:

- [Classics queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)
- [Quorums queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html)

They have different behaviours.